# $_POST not working properly

Tags: php, post

This is my Form

```
<div id="dateSelectors" >
  <form action="#" method="post" style="display:inline">
    <label for="fromDate">From :&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="fromDate" class="datepicker"/>
    <label from="toDate">To :&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="toDate" class="datepicker"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" class="add_btn" id="go_btn" name="go_btn"/>
    <input type="submit" value="View All" class="add_btn" id="viewAll" name="viewAll"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my php code in same page:

```
if(isset($_POST['go_btn'])){
        $stmt;
        if(isset($_POST['toDate']))
        $to=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($_POST['toDate']));
        if(isset($_POST['fromDate']))
        $from=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($_POST['fromDate']));
    }
```

When i fill the field Like this
From:01/07/2014 To:21/07/2014.

I get:
echo $_POST['fromDate'] as 01/07/2014.
but $_POST['toDate'] as 01/01/1970.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Since the data you are talking about is being sent and received then the issue has nothing to do with `HTTP POST` operations on either the client or the server.

Comment: I guess it's datepicker's problem

Comment: The problem obviously lies in that part of your application which generates the data you are talking about, namely the datepicker.

Comment: Another guess (!!!): 21/07/2014 is not a valid date, but it should rather be 07/21/2014 ???

Comment: datepicker is working fine i used `var_dump` to see this...

Comment: @JohnB Not true for the UK, and probably many other places

Comment: @Johnsmith Please provide var_dump of $_POST

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, but your label has 'from' property instead of 'for'

Comment: @user574632: I know that, but does the system know that as well? See Bernd Ott's answer below.

Comment: Off topic: Having the form and the validation/processing code in the same page is not a good practice. Have an HTML file for the form, and a separate PHP file for validation/processing. When processing is done, **redirect**.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jquery datepicker ?

If yes, you need to instance each element :

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$to=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($_POST['toDate']));
```

I looks like that `strtotime` doesn't find a valid date if parsed. Ensure that php is using YOUR locales! I'm guess this because when your are output a date, you are using date-formats.

You can set the local with php function `setlocale`.